# How can I, on click, be redirected to another page and, at the same time, start a countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with three columns. In the first there are a series of links. The second shows a timer for each link that can range from one minute to 24 hours. The third is currently empty. What my page should do when a user clicks a link:

1. The link changes color.
2. I am redirected to that page in new tab.
3. A countdown starts from the time indicated in column 2 down to zero.
4. The countdown is shown in column 3 where the word "ready" will appear when the time expires.

I managed to make my own html page while having trouble with javascript. I have found many solutions on the web that, however, either make me a countdown, or redirect me to a url, but never both things together. I enclose my example below. Thanks to those willing to help me.

```js
function setCustomTimer()
  {
    setInterval(showtimer, 1000);
    return false;
  }

function showtimer() {
  if(seconds == 00)
  {
    seconds = 60;
    minutes--;
  }
  seconds--;

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    seconds;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="it">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:#7B68EE;font-family: "Arial Rounded MT","Liberation Serif", "School Times","Times New Roman";color:black;font-weight:200;font-size:120%
        }
        .centered table {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }
        table:{width: 700px;border: 4px solid #000000;border-collapse: collapse
        }
        th,td:nth-child(1){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: left;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        }
        th,td:nth-child(2){color:black;width: 100px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        }
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        th,td:nth-child(3){color:black;width: 300px;height: 10px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding: .1em
        a:link{color:black;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bolder
        }
        a:visited {color:black;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bolder
        }
        A:hover{color:red;text-decoration:blink
        }
        A:active{color:green;text-decoration:underline
        }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <table class="centered table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>site
                        </th>
                        <th>timer (hh:mm:ss)
                        </th>
                        <th>countdown then ready
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <span style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <a href="http://google.com" id="winapp"onclick="openPortal( this )"target="_blank">Google
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                                    <script>
                                    function openPortal( elem ) {elem.style.color="#A9A9A9";
                                    }
                                    </script>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>00:30:00
                        </td>
                        <td>......
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you are redirecting to a new page, then changing the link color is irrelevant because you won't be on the first page any long to see the link. Also, any code on that first page will cease and code on the new page will run, so you'll need to pass the data from page 1 that you need to use on page 2. This can be done in many ways, but `localStorage` is an easy option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good first attempt, but maybe this will get you a bit further along and start the creative juices flowing. You're missing a lot of actual attempt I think so far, there's room to improve and please work on your structure as a good habit to have -- but I cleaned up a bit and first one is free, welcome to SO :)

```js
// This is just a quick way to avoid repetitively typing document.getElementById (kind of like what jquery does).
$ = (id) => { return document.getElementById(id) }

// We define the variables we need by identifying the html elements and providing the default time number.
// We'll use 'let' instead of var since we don't need them defined until they're initialized anyway.
let secs = 30,
    link = $('url'),
    time = $('time'),
    count = $('countdown');
    
    // Assign the variable we defined above to display in the html elements we defined.
    time.innerHTML = secs;
    count.innerHTML = secs;
      
// Provide the method called from 'onclick' on the link url. I like to use "fat arrow" usually just to avoid issues with 'this' scope, I suggest giving it a google for further explanation.     
startTimer = () => {

  // To open the window, uncomment. Left commented out for this example on SO.
  // window.open(link.href, '_blank');

  // We create the interval counter that will execute the embedded 'countdown' function on each of the 1 second iterations.
  let tiks = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  // Add a little flare by setting a couple of the html elements font color
  link.style.color = 'red';
  count.style.color = 'red';

  // I like to declare embedded functions the old fashioned way for easier skim reading.
  // So here on every iteration we check to see if the value of interval is less than 0 and react accordingly.
  // Once we reach less than zero we do a little clean up and change the user display, if we haven't reached it yet than we continue to reduce the timer number by 1 each iteration.
  function countdown() {
    if (secs == -1) {
      // This is important. Always clear an interval / timeout after use.
      clearInterval(tiks); 
      link.style.color = 'green';
      time.style.color = 'green';
      count.style.color = 'green';
    } else {
      // Since if we reach here we're still counting down, so we update the display and reduce the timer number by 1 for each iteration.
      count.innerHTML = secs;
      secs--;
    }
  }
        
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#7B68EE;
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT","Liberation Serif", "School Times","Times New Roman";
  color:black;
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:120%
}
.centered table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
  width: 700px;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
th, td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: .1em
}
td {
  padding: 1rem;
}

a:link{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bolder
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration:blink
}
a:active{
  color: green;
  text-decoration:underline
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>site
      </th>
      <th>timer (hh:mm:ss)
      </th>
      <th>countdown then ready
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="url" onclick="startTimer()" target="_blank">
          Google
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        00:00:<span id="time"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="countdown"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```